# Faster alternatives too WINAPI ReadProcessMemory

Tags: winapi, kernel, windows-kernel

I am making an application that reads a target process's memory. The memory that I read needs to be as up-to-date as possible, and the total memory read time preferably <1ms (right now I'm hovering around 0.8ms).

Due to the nature of my application, I have lots of `ReadProcessMemory()` calls that can't be reduced down through caching or similar methods. I'm wondering, is it possible to read process memory faster? I'm willing to put my application inside a kernel driver if the performance boost is big enough.

What are my choices?

Comment: Surely only kernel code will be able to do better

Comment: You can inject into the target process so that you can access memory directly through pointers. I think this is the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

Calling NtReadVirtualMemory will give you a 1% increase in speed, not very exciting.

You can increase efficiency by reading large blocks of memory, and accesses each individual variable you need.  If you're reading offset 0x8 and 0x200 in 2 different calls, then you should just read the entire structure instead and then locally parse it.

NtWriteVirtualMemory can give you an almost 100% increase in speed over regular WriteProcessMemory in certain situations.

Other than that, injecting and having direct access to the memory is the best route.